# How do I show a File Saveas dialog from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I'm creating an extension for Google Chrome that converts a webpage into a PDF file. From the JavaScript background page, the URL, DOM, and the path are passed to the NPAPI DLL, where the conversion happens. For now, the path is hard-coded. I want to add a File Saveas dialog to the extension, and grab the path from it, with the file name, and pass it to the NPAPI DLL. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do the file save-as dialog in the extension if you are just going to have it pass to the NPAPI dll? If it were me I'd just have the NPAPI dll pop up the save dialog.

Comment: Modal dialogs from out-of-process plugins? While i haven't written any extensions i'd imagine bringing a file dialog up from the browser would be much less problematic (and platform independent).

Comment: I'm using one in one of my plugins and it works fine on both windows and mac. See https://gist.github.com/1368648 for the code I'm using (intended to work with a FireBreath plugin)

Comment: Looks like I finally got it to work with Windows API GetSaveFileName. However, I might like to switch to something platform independent, just as Georg suggested.